# Where shall I put my util shell scripts in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have read the Linux FHS, but still feel a little confuse. If I have some utility shell scripts, shall I put them in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin or ~/bin?

The FHS says the most user commands goes to /usr/bin, but it also says that administrater should install unpackaged app or host specific stuff in /usr/local, does that means the /usr/local/bin is a better place for my own scripts? Maybe ~/bin is better? I want to know the best way / conventions to do this. Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Linux system administration; it would probably be a better fit for [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks for remind, Ill log my linux relate questions in that site.

Comment: For the record: an answer to a similar question can be found at http://serverfault.com/questions/139451/where-is-a-good-permanent-place-to-install-custom-bash-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't put *anything* unpackaged inside `/usr/bin`, there's already way too much mess in there without adding unpackaged stuff. Leave it to the package manager.

Now, if they are system-wide scripts, I would put them into `/usr/local/bin`, which is usually way less crowded, is accessible to everyone and editable only by root; if, instead, they are just for your user, you should put them into `~/bin`.